# Gradle not downloading dependencies in intelliJ idea 2016.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I've been having this issue with Gradle where it is failing to download dependencies after making a new release.

Here is the error:
[image]

I've tried to delete module and re-add it, restart IntelliJ, reimport multiple times but it gives me the same error every time.

Here is the link for the dependency it is "failing" to download.

https://jitpack.io/com/github/Jonatino/Abendigo-Offset-Scanner/1.3/Abendigo-Offset-Scanner-1.3.jar

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: The problem looks to be Gradle or networking related. Intellij just runs a Gradle process.

Comment: Does "native" gradle (run from terminal) show that error?

Comment: @Roman https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91292881/ShareX/2016/07/powershell_2016-07-18_15-59-32.png Fails with gradle build as well.

Comment: another way,excute 'gradle idea' in currencu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by running 'gradle build --refresh-dependencies'

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of people having trouble with Anti virus software preventing dependency downloads. Try disabling it momentarily and then try again. This is a slight shot in the dark, but i hope it helps.

Comment: Good idea..but unfortunately I don't user any type of antivirus. Thanks for helping though :D